# How to sample from another dataset based on factors?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr, sample

I have two data sets. `df_sample` contains some measured data `param` across sites and quadrants (with replicates). I want to use this dataset to populate `df`

```
set.seed(111)

#This is the dataset I want to draw the sample from
site <- rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 20)
quad <- rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), rep = 12)
param <- rnorm(60,5,1)

df_sample <- data.frame(site,quad, param)


#This is the dataset I want to add the sampling to
month <- rep(c("J","J","J","F","M"), each = 5)
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1","2"), each = 5)
quad <- rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), rep = 5)

df <- data.frame(month,site,quad)
```

Notice that the first dataset just has the sites where param was measured multiple times across various quadrants. Now, in `df` I want to create a new column param. For each month and site, this param will randomly sample from only its corresponding site and quadrant. So essentially, each site and quadrant can take one of three values. How can I achieve this?

`df$param <- sample(df_sample$param)`

```
As an example `df` could look like this

month site quad param
  J    1     1    4.8236
  J    1     2    3.502
  J    1     3    6.84
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
setDT(df_sample)[,list(param=list(param)),by=list(site,quad)][
  setDT(df),
  on = c("site","quad")][,param:=sapply(param, sample, 1)][]
 
   site quad    param month
 1:    1    1 4.826326     J
 2:    1    2 3.502573     J
 3:    1    3 6.845636     J
 4:    1    4 5.394054     J
 5:    1    5 4.506038     J
 6:    2    1 1.886783     J
 7:    2    2 4.058643     J
 8:    2    3 5.334256     J
 9:    2    4 4.840423     J
10:    2    5 5.326549     J
11:    3    1 4.152732     J
12:    3    2 5.331380     J
13:    3    3 6.805868     J
14:    3    4 7.485662     J
15:    3    5 5.741972     J
16:    1    1 5.140278     F
17:    1    2 4.593401     F
18:    1    3 6.845636     F
19:    1    4 5.394054     F
20:    1    5 5.797529     F
21:    2    1 1.886783     M
22:    2    2 4.883845     M
23:    2    3 5.189737     M
24:    2    4 4.379142     M
25:    2    5 2.734004     M
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an ID column to `df_sample` labeling each replicate as 1, 2, or 3. (I call it `run`.) Add a corresponding randomly selected `run` column to `df`. Then join:

```
library(dplyr)
df_sample = df_sample %>% 
  group_by(site, quad) %>%
  mutate(run = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

df %>%
  mutate(run = sample(1:3, size = n(), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  left_join(df_sample)
# Joining, by = c("site", "quad", "run")
#    month site quad run    param
# 1      J    1    1   2 5.140278
# 2      J    1    2   2 3.502573
# 3      J    1    3   1 4.688376
# 4      J    1    4   1 2.697654
# 5      J    1    5   3 5.797529
# 6      J    2    1   2 5.598254
# 7      J    2    2   2 3.158466
# 8      J    2    3   2 7.718056
# 9      J    2    4   3 3.379530
# 10     J    2    5   3 2.734004
# 11     J    3    1   1 3.824274
# 12     J    3    2   2 5.331380
# 13     J    3    3   3 5.914242
# 14     J    3    4   3 5.358625
# 15     J    3    5   3 5.175096
# 16     F    1    1   2 5.140278
# 17     F    1    2   1 4.669264
# 18     F    1    3   3 6.845636
# 19     F    1    4   1 2.697654
# 20     F    1    5   2 4.506038
# 21     M    2    1   3 1.886783
# 22     M    2    2   1 5.346964
# 23     M    2    3   2 7.718056
# 24     M    2    4   2 5.191244
# 25     M    2    5   2 3.698704
```

---

If there are variable sample sizes per group, something like this:

```
df_sample = df_sample %>% 
  group_by(site, quad) %>%
  mutate(run = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

df_sample_n = df_sample %>%
  group_by(site, quad) %>%
  summarize(n_run = max(run))

df %>%
  left_join(df_sample_n) %>%
  mutate(run = sapply(n_run, \(x) sample(x, size = 1))) %>%
  left_join(df_sample)
```

Comment: We could just alternatively use `slice_sample(n = 1)` to simplify

Comment: @thesixmax doing `slice_sample` before the join makes a lot of assumptions. Doing `slice_sample` after the join is less efficient. I like the clarity and scalability of this approach.

Comment: I am curious about what assumptions we are making by using `slice_sample` prior to the join - please elaborate?

Comment: If you use `slice_sample` prior to the join then every `month` in `df` with the same `quad` and `site` values will get the same `param`. You're assuming you want that. I don't think OP wants that - I think OP wants an independent draw every month.

Comment: I would further suggest that it's good form to have enough ID columns to uniquely identify any row. Adding the `run` column to `df_sample` seems to me like best practice - I think it should have been there already. If OP has other uses for this data I think it's likely that the `run` column will be useful.

Comment: Correct, good point, I was too quick on my feet. Your approach also makes it easier to work with e.g. varying number of samples per site/quad further down the line.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. However, it breaks down when there are less than 3 replicates for each quadrant. In my (messy) dataset, there are a few quadrant in every sites in `df_sample` that have only 1 or 2, or even sometimes 4 replicates. For 1 or 2 replicates it generates NAs. Is there anyway to keep the loop more general?

Comment: Yeah, see the edits at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `join` with `multiple = "any"`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 or above required
df %>% 
  left_join(df_sample, multiple = "any")
```

Or `multiple = "all"` + `slice_sample` (since the documentation does not state that `multiple = "any"` is sampling), it might be safer to use this option:

```r
df %>% 
  left_join(df_sample, multiple = "all") %>% 
  slice_sample(by = c(month, site, quad))
```

output

```r
Joining with `by = join_by(site, quad)`
   month site quad    param
1      J    1    1 5.235221
2      J    1    2 4.669264
3      J    1    3 4.688376
4      J    1    4 2.697654
5      J    1    5 4.829124
6      J    2    1 5.361662
7      J    2    2 5.346964
8      J    2    3 5.189737
9      J    2    4 4.840423
10     J    2    5 5.326549
11     J    3    1 3.824274
12     J    3    2 3.878784
13     J    3    3 3.638096
14     J    3    4 5.481125
15     J    3    5 5.741972
16     F    1    1 5.235221
17     F    1    2 4.669264
18     F    1    3 4.688376
19     F    1    4 2.697654
20     F    1    5 4.829124
21     M    2    1 5.361662
22     M    2    2 5.346964
23     M    2    3 5.189737
24     M    2    4 4.840423
25     M    2    5 5.326549
```

Comment: I get an errorr when I run it with the second code: Joining, by = c("site", "quad")
Error in `slice_sample()`:
! `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• by = c(month, site, quad)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: You need dplyr 1.1.0 or above. If not update your package